# Priority queue in GoLang using channels

Tags: go, deadlock, priority-queue, channel

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX5cj.png)

In the above image is the question I need to provide a solution to. here is the solution I have come up with (must be coded in Go). I am getting the deadlock error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /home/kypriank/Assignment 5/priorityqueue.go:42 +0x1a3

goroutine 17 [chan send]:
main.priorityQueue(0xc420080060, 0xc4200800c0)
    /home/kypriank/Assignment 5/priorityqueue.go:22 +0x1a2
created by main.main
    /home/kypriank/Assignment 5/priorityqueue.go:40 +0xe5
exit status 2
```

Was wondering if somebody could assist me in figuring out where my code is messing up(the main function has some code to test my solution):

```
package main

var numOrder [20] int
var mesOrder [] PriorityMessage
var pri int
var a int

type PriorityMessage struct {
    Priority int // between 0 and 9
    Message string
}

func priorityQueue(west chan PriorityMessage, east chan string) {
    incomming := <-west
    if numOrder[incomming.Priority] == 10 {
        numOrder[incomming.Priority] = incomming.Priority
    }else {numOrder[incomming.Priority+1] = incomming.Priority}
    mesOrder = append(mesOrder, incomming)
    for i := 0; i < len(numOrder); i++ {if numOrder[i] != 10 {pri = 
numOrder[i]; a = i; break}}
    for i := 0; i < len(mesOrder); i++ {
        if pri == mesOrder[i].Priority {
            east <- (mesOrder[i]).Message
            numOrder[a] = 10
            mesOrder = append(mesOrder[:i], mesOrder[i+1:]...) 
        }
    }
}

var west chan PriorityMessage
var east chan string

func printToScreen() {
    for {println(<- east)}
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < len(numOrder); i++ {numOrder[i] = 10}
    west = make(chan PriorityMessage)
    east = make(chan string)
    go priorityQueue(west, east)
    west <- PriorityMessage{1, "one"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{0, "zero"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{2, "two"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{1, "another one"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{0, "another zero"}
    go printToScreen()
    select {} // to allow all messages to be printed
}
```

Comment: Priority Queue is standard data type in CS and does not require concurrency to implement - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Usual_implementation

Comment: unfortunately, the assignment requires me to implement this using concurrency. But thank you for the input Dimitry :) the majority of the code is provided. The only part of the code i must implement myself is the PriorityQueue function.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really look at the priority queue behavior but instead focused ont the deadlock.

So you have a few problems that will give you a deadlock:

1. You are only reading from `west` once, however you are writing to it several times. This means that it will block when you write `zero`. Maybe add a `for` loop.
2. `go printToScreen()` is after all the writes to `west`. This means that when your go routine reading from `west` and then writing to `east` gets to the writing part, it will block because nothing is reading from `east`.
3. Empty select (`select{}`). While this will block the main go routine, it will do so indefinitely. This will cause a deadlock panic once all the other go routines close out.

I changed your code to this:

```
package main

import "time"

var numOrder [20]int
var mesOrder []PriorityMessage
var pri int
var a int

type PriorityMessage struct {
    Priority int // between 0 and 9
    Message  string
}

func priorityQueue(west chan PriorityMessage, east chan string) {
    for {
        incomming := <-west
        if numOrder[incomming.Priority] == 10 {
            numOrder[incomming.Priority] = incomming.Priority
        } else {
            numOrder[incomming.Priority+1] = incomming.Priority
        }
        mesOrder = append(mesOrder, incomming)
        for i := 0; i < len(numOrder); i++ {
            if numOrder[i] != 10 {
                pri =
                    numOrder[i]
                a = i
                break
            }
        }
        for i := 0; i < len(mesOrder); i++ {
            if pri == mesOrder[i].Priority {
                east <- (mesOrder[i]).Message
                numOrder[a] = 10
                mesOrder = append(mesOrder[:i], mesOrder[i+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
}

var west chan PriorityMessage
var east chan string

func printToScreen() {
    for {
        println(<-east)
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < len(numOrder); i++ {
        numOrder[i] = 10
    }
    go printToScreen()
    west = make(chan PriorityMessage)
    east = make(chan string)
    go priorityQueue(west, east)
    west <- PriorityMessage{1, "one"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{0, "zero"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{2, "two"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{1, "another one"}
    west <- PriorityMessage{0, "another zero"}

    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
}
```

And go the following results:

```
one
zero
two
another one
another zero
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth explanation and the solution you provided poy! as i mentioned before, unfortunately i am not allowed to alter any code other than the code within the priorityQueue function. The variables that i created were numOrder, mesOrder, pri, and a. so other than those 4, and anything within the priorityQueue function cannot be changed.

Comment: Fair enough, but that means you must constantly consume from west and not be blocked by east. So Insert the for loop in the function and then when writing to east, do so within a new go routine.